# Como tornar seu programa confiavel - segurança do windows

Tags: c#, winforms, windows, segurança

Finalizei uma etapa de um programa e vamos começar a colocar em produção, porem, ao executar o programa é sempre exibido a mensagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque devo fazer, para tornar meu programa confiável? e parar de exibir essa mensagem?

Obs: não quero desativar o UCA do Windows.

Comment: Vide http://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/desativo-mensagem/754771/

Comment: Pesquise sobre code signing. Em resumo, você precisa comprar um certificado específico para isto, de uma certificadora reconhecida, e assinar o executável (seja com a ferramenta signtool.exe ou outros métodos similares). Quanto ao aviso específico da imagem, parte do problema é o fato de estar querendo executar de unidade mapeada.

Comment: @Bacco por favor, mova seu "comentário" para uma resposta. :)

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi teria que elaborar mais, só "pincelei por cima" do assunto para facilitar para o Thomas pesquisar. Tou meio enrolado com outros assuntos pra elaborar, mas se você ou outro usuário quiser responder com mais detalhes, fique à vontade (é bom lembrar de elaborar sobre o code signing, e também explicar os critérios que o windows usa para determinar que um arquivo de rede não é confiável, além dos marcados com _stream_ NTFS como baixados da internet)

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
Passei por um problema semelhante com o AVAST.
Fiz um certificado digital para assinar meu código pela Certsign:

https://www.certisign.com.br/certificado-digital/assinatura-codigo/authenticode

Para utilizar este certificado é muito simples, quando você entra na parte de publicação do seu software, verá uma tela de publicação terá uma aba:

SIGNING

Nesta tela você poderá colocar o certificado digital e assinar seu código.[image: Exemplo de assinatura de código]

Depois que fiz isso, nunca mais tive problemas com AVAST ou segurança do Windows.